# Get user input while continually reading stdin from a pipe in Python?

Tags: python, stdin

Given a program called `interactive` that starts like this:

```
% tail -f logfile | interactive
```

In Python, we can reset `stdin` to something other than `stdin` by overwriting the reference:

```
import sys 

text = sys.stdin.read() 

# rebind sys.stdin to tty 
sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty") 
user_in = input("Selection? : ")
```

However, this does not work if we need to continue to read from the file we piped in forever, as the original `stdin` pipe is not let go. Is there a way to take the input from what we are piping and move it to a separate pipe so that we can still use `stdin` to get user input?

Comment: I think it might be possible to do in two steps - given a named pipe is open at, say, `/tmp/my_pipe`, you could have `tail` output to that pipe, and then independently have python open and read from that same pipe - thus freeing up stdin for user input. Doing something like `tail -f logfile > /tmp/my_pipe && python interactive.py`

Comment: That said, have you considered trying to do the entire thing in a single python program? You could actually attach a pipe/file descriptor to a `subprocess` call of your own, which would simplify the issue as you wouldn't need to create a proxy like this.

Comment: The goal was to make this program work optionally either way; I can call it like `interactive -e 'tail -f logfile'`and spawn a subprocess with that command. That all works, but I really wanted to be able to pipe to it as well because that syntax feels more natural. Good call RE tail to a separate pipe, but you are correct, the subprocess method is significantly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as their status as file streams goes, there is *nothing* special about `stdin/stdout/stderr`<sup>1</sup>. Once the program is started, you can treat them like any regular file descriptor. So the idea of rebinding `stdin` is not necessary. Instead, this really seems to be more of a question about how to set up concurrent input streams.

My first inclination is to use a couple threads, but I'm sure this could be done using `async/await` and probably some other ways, too. Threads should be fine in this case, since both threads will end up IO bound and should release the GIL (everyone likes to get fired up about the GIL). This gets pretty close (not perfect, but within the ballpark...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import threading
from time import sleep

user_input = ""

def tty_reader():
    global user_input
    read_fd = open("/dev/tty", 'r')
    while 1:
        print("interactive-% ", end="", flush=True)
        user_input = read_fd.readline() # block for input
        print("\nUser Input: " + str(user_input), end="", flush=True)

def pipe_reader():
    while 1:
        stdin_text = sys.stdin.readline() # block for input
        if stdin_text != user_input:
            print("\nPipe Message: " + str(stdin_text), end="", flush=True)

t_tty_reader = threading.Thread(target=tty_reader)
t_pipe_reader = threading.Thread(target=pipe_reader)
t_pipe_reader.start()
sleep(3) # to let the existing 'tail' lines finish printing
t_tty_reader.start()
```

save it to a file, `chmod 755` it, and run like this:

```
tail -f <some file> | ./<python script>
```

This starts 2 threads. One reads from `/dev/tty` and the other reads from the original `stdin` which should be attached to the `stdout` of the `tail -f` command. Both threads spend most of their time blocking on input. As I said, this could be better, but it shows the general idea.

---

<sub>1: They are still kind of special for a few reasons though: you get them for free; they are pre-plumbed in a certain standardized configuration; they get some special treatment as devices in `/dev`; child processes inherit them.</sub>